# ¿Cómo mejorar el rendimiento para evitar el error: USER HAS EXCEEDED THE MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS?

Tags: mysql, laravel, error500

Desde una aplicación móvil mando cientos de contratos hacia la pagina web.

En esta ultima por cada contrato obtengo la información de la Base de datos mysql (phpmyadmin)
y  lo siguiente es comenzar a validar ciertos valores y en base a ellos
hago UPDATES y mas CONSULTAS a la BD, pero esto me esta regresando el error max_user_connections.

Y mi duda es como podría mejorar esto si tengo que consultar la información, hacer actualizaciones y obtener mas datos?

Las consultas las hago de la siguiente manera.(Ejemplos)

```
$existeContrato = DB::select("SELECT id, estatus_estadocontrato FROM contratos WHERE id = '" . $contrato['ID_CONTRATO'] . "'");
```

Una actualización la hago de esta manera.

```
 DB::table("contratos")->where("id", "=", $contrato['ID_CONTRATO'])->where("id_franquicia", "=", $idFranquicia)->update([
         "datos" => $contrato['DATOS']
         ]);
```

El detalle es que tengo que hacer esto por cada contrato y hacer múltiples consultas de este tipo.

Comment: Seguramente el problema no son las consultas en si, que funcionan, sino el algoritmo para lanzarlas, o quizás deberias agruparlas de algun modo para que no sean tan seguidas y en una sola consulta actualizar o insertar muchos registros. De este modo costaria más exceder el max_user_connections.

Comment: Algo que talvez omití es que son múltiples usuarios al mismo tiempo haciendo esto, eso sumado a esto creo que es donde pudiera estar el problema, pero no se como solucionarlo, no se si se tenga que cerrar alguna conexión o simplemente el proceso tarda un poco mas de lo habitual y se queda abierta la conexión.

Comment: Desconozco Laravel, y no se si su conexión a la base de datos es persistente, quizas por ahi van los tiros tambien, ni si tu servidor tiene un keep alive demasiado alto (no estoy seguro de si eso influye en la BD, lo dudo, pero ya puestos)